# How to get a value when clicking a button in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a basic form that includes two text inputs and one button using a project created from the react native CLI.

```
const Signup = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const handleChangeUsername = () => {
    setUsername(username)
  }
  const handleChangePassword = () => {
    setPassword(password)
  }

  const btnSignup = () => {
    // auth()
    // .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(setUsername,setPassword)
    // .then(() => {
    //   console.log('User account created & signed in!');
    // })
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <TextInput onChangeText={handleChangeUsername}> Kullanıcı Adı </TextInput>{' '}
        <TextInput onChangeText={handleChangePassword}> Password </TextInput>{' '}
      </View>{' '}
      <View>
        {' '}
        <Button onPress={btnSignup} title="TIKLA" />{' '}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Signup
```

I can't use the `btnSignup` method because when it's run give an error. What is the issue here?

Comment: It would be useful to provide the error as well.

Comment: when I write console.log(setUsername) it's give [Function bound dispatchSetState]

Comment: Selam. handleChangeUsername function param almalı. Aldığın paramsi sonra setUsername vereceksin. param console log yaz bak once. ya direk value olcak yada e.target.value

Answer (score 0):

Id replace your text inputs as the below

```
<View>
<TextInput onChangeText={setUsername} value={username} placeholder="Username" />
<TextInput onChangeText={setPassword} value={password} placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry={true}/>
</View>
```

I then get no errors when clicking button. If youre trying to console log the username write console.log(username) instead of console.log(setUsername)

Answer (score 0):

1. You are trying to console.log(setUsername) which is a state setter
   function. If you want to log the value you need to write:
   `console.log(username)`
2. and also you need to update your handleChangeUsername and
   handleChangePassword to receive input value and update state which
   would look like this: `const handleChangeUsername = (value) => {   setUsername(value); }`

and if you want to log username nad password you can do it inside btnSignup which would look like this:

```
const btnSignup = () => {
  console.log('Username:', username);
  console.log('Password:', password);
}
```